# React: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'categoryName') on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my Product detail class and in this class, I had reached product service the error was only caused when I used  product.category.categoryName.
In product service class I am using Axios to interact with API

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router'
import { Button, Card, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import ProductService from '../services/productService'

export default function ProductDetail() {
  const { id } = useParams()

  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    let productService = new ProductService();
    productService.getProductById(id).then(result => setProduct(result.data.data))
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <Card.Group>
        <Card fluid>
          <Card.Content>
            <Image
              size='medium'
              src='https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/steve.jpg'
            />
            <Card.Header style={{ marginTop: '0.5em' }}>{product.productName}</Card.Header>
            <Card.Meta></Card.Meta>
            <Card.Description>Units in Stock :
              {product.unitsInStock}
            </Card.Description>
            <Card.Description>Unit Price :
              {product.unitPrice}$
            </Card.Description>
            <Card.Description>
              {product.category.categoryName}
            </Card.Description>
          </Card.Content>
          <Card.Content extra>
            <div className='ui two buttons'>
              <Button basic color='green'>
                Add to Cart
              </Button>
              <Button basic color='red'>
                Add to Favorites
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Card.Content>
        </Card>

      </Card.Group>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In my ProductService Class

```
import axios from "axios";

export default class ProductService{

    getProducts(){
        return axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/products/getAll")
    }

    getProductById(productId){
        return axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/products/getByProductId?productId=${productId}`)
    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot of what my API returns when I send an id
[And my API returns an object like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS8LC.png)

And I am getting that error
(Line 32 is the line starts with Card.Description includes product.category.categoryName)

```
ProductDetail.jsx:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'categoryName')
    at ProductDetail (ProductDetail.jsx:32:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
ProductDetail @ ProductDetail.jsx:32
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
ProductDetail.jsx:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'categoryName')
    at ProductDetail (ProductDetail.jsx:32:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
ProductDetail @ ProductDetail.jsx:32
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <ProductDetail> component:

    at ProductDetail (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1033:62)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46558:5)
    at div
    at GridColumn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51973:24)
    at div
    at GridRow (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:52083:24)
    at div
    at Grid (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51857:22)
    at div
    at Dashboard
    at div
    at Container (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53978:24)
    at div
    at App
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46491:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:45300:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25892
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
ProductDetail.jsx:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'categoryName')
    at ProductDetail (ProductDetail.jsx:32:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)
```

Comment: When the component renders for the first time, `product.category` is undefined and trying to access `product.category.categoryName` causes the error. You should render the card conditionally.

Comment: Because when you try to access `product.unitsInStock` `unitsInStock` returns `undefined` and you are good, but with `product.category.categoryName` you try to access a property (`categoryName`) of an undefined object - `product.category`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you run `setProduct(result.data.data)`, your `product` variable is an empty object. You render method executes before the API response's `then` function. You simply need to check `product ?` and render the content only if `product` has been populated. You can use the opportunity to add a loading bar if it's not (or some other solution for empty data state)

Comment: But why it is only throwing an error on the category part?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do something like this:

```
{ product.category !== undefined && product.category.categoryName }
```